# Optimizar el código (menos líneas)

Tags: java

Hola soy nuevo en esto de programar en Java, quería saber si este código se podría optimizar un poco más, no se, mis conocimientos me dan hasta ahí.

El programa básicamente lo que debe hacer es preguntar datos como lo son nombre de la carrera, nombre estudiante y escoger un horarios (diurno o nocturno) cada uno con su respectivo precio, debe tener restricciones de que los datos coincidan con el tipo de datos, o sea `String` que sea `String` y `double` que sea `double`, cosa que no se como hacer.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Esto llevo de momento:

```
 package Principal;

    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


    public class Vista extends Principal {
        public Vista(){
            String nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba el nombre del estudiante");
            String carrera = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba el nombre de la carrera");
            String deportistas []= {"Si","No"};
            String matricula []= {"980.000","1.150.000"};
            String jornada []= {"Diurna","Nocturna"};
            double descuentos = 0;
            String mensaje ="";
            String promedio []= {"Si","No"};
            //diurno o nocturno
            String Jornadas = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"elija el horario ","",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null, jornada, jornada[0]);
            //deportista
            String deportista = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null," ¿eres deportista? ", "",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null, deportistas, deportistas[0]);
            //promedio
            String promedios = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"¿ su promedio es alto ? ",""
                ,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null, promedio,promedio[0]);
            double diurno =980000;
            double nocturna =1150000;
            double valor =0;
            double vlrDescuento = 0;

            switch(Jornadas){
                case "Diurna":
                        if (deportista == "Si" && promedios == "Si"){
                            valor=diurno; 
                            descuentos = 0.05+0.15+0.20; 
                            vlrDescuento = diurno -(diurno*descuentos);
                            mensaje=" se aplico descuento del 5% por ser diurno, 15% por tener el promedio alto y 20% por ser deortista ";                        
                        }else if (deportista == "Si" && promedios == "No"){
                            valor=diurno;
                            descuentos = 0.05+0.20;
                            vlrDescuento= diurno - (diurno*descuentos);
                            mensaje= "se aplico descuentos del 5% por ser diurno y 20% por ser deportista";
                        }else if (deportista == "No" && promedios == "No"){
                            valor=diurno;
                            descuentos =  0.05;
                            vlrDescuento=diurno - (diurno * descuentos);
                             mensaje= "se aplico descuentos del 5% por ser diurno";
                        }else if (deportista == "No" && promedios == "Si"){
                            valor = diurno;
                            descuentos = 0.05+0.15;
                            vlrDescuento = diurno - (diurno * descuentos);
                             mensaje= "se aplico descuentos del 5% por ser diurno y 15% por el promedio alto";
                        }break;
                case "Nocturna":
                    if (deportista == "Si" && promedios=="Si"){
                            valor=nocturna;
                            descuentos = 0.10+0.15+0.20;
                            vlrDescuento = nocturna -(nocturna*descuentos);
                            mensaje=" se aplico descuento del 10% por ser nocturna, 15% por tener el promedio alto y 20% por ser deortista "; 
                        }else if (deportista == "Si" && promedios == "No"){
                            valor=nocturna;
                            descuentos = 0.10+0.20;
                            vlrDescuento= nocturna - (nocturna*descuentos);
                            mensaje= "se aplico descuentos del 10% por ser nocturna y 20% por ser deportista";
                        }else if (deportista== "No" && promedios == "No"){
                            valor=nocturna;
                            descuentos = 0.10;
                            vlrDescuento=nocturna - (nocturna * descuentos);
                             mensaje= "se aplico descuentos del 10% por ser nocturna";
                        }else if (deportista == "No" && promedios == "Si"){
                            valor= nocturna;
                            descuentos = 0.10+0.15;
                            vlrDescuento = nocturna - (nocturna *descuentos);
                             mensaje= "se aplico descuentos del 10% por ser nocturna y 15% por el promedio alto";
                        }break;
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "nombre = "+ nombre +"\n"
               +"carrera = "+ carrera +"\n"
               +"jornada = "+ Jornadas +"\n"
               +"valor neto = "+ valor +"\n"
               +"total a pagar = "+ vlrDescuento +"\n"
               +"por motivos de = "+ mensaje +"\n");

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay una sola optimizacion valida en ese código, y es ese `switch` gigante que hace siempre lo mismo. No vas a optimizar código realmente, pero va a ser mas cómodo de leer y visible.

Tu `switch` básicamente verifica algunas variables, y según eso hace un calculo y muestra un mensaje.

todo eso, se puede hacer con algunos if para que se vea mejor.

**Nota, te recomendaron usar objetos, y acá no ganarías nada, pero para la próxima vez seria interesante que lo empezaras a ver**

Ahora, veamos como hacer que tu código haga lo mismo que hace ahora, pero un poco mas **fácil de ver**

```
// aca vamos a ir guardando el mensaje a mostrar
string mensaje = "";
//aca vamos a ir guardando el descuento aplicado
doble descuento = 0;
//estos son tus valores de origen.. esto se podría simplicar pasandole a valor directamente
// estos números dentro del primer if
double diurno =980000;
double nocturna =1150000;
//aca vamos a guardar el valor de origen que necesitamos
valor = 0;
if (jornadas.equals("diurno")) {
    valor = diurno;
    descuento = 0.5;
    mensaje = "se aplico descuento del 5% por ser diurno";
} else {
    valor = nocturna;
    descuento = 0.10;
    mensaje = "se aplico descuentos del 10% por ser nocturna";
}
if (deportista.equals("Si")) {
    descuento += 0.20;
    mensaje += ", 20% por ser deportista";
} 
if (promedios.equals("Si")) {
    descuento += 0.15;
    mensaje += ", 15% por el promedio alto"; 
}
//calculamos el valor
valor = valor - (valor * descuento);
//sigue tu codigo para mostrar...
```

el único problema que tiene esto, es que al final falta un y... porque esta todo dividido por comas.. pero eso es algo que podrías solucionar buscando la ultima coma y reemplazandola por una y.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas optimo que puedes hacer es cambiarlo todo a programacion orientada a objetos (POO), Java es un lenguaje que todo lo toma por objetos.

Puedes seguir tutoriales en Youtube de POO.

Otra cosa, es que no es obligacion usar solo el tipo de dato String y double, por ahi puedes empezar mejorando 3 vectores que has creado, esos los puedes cambiar de tipo de dato a boolean.

y si quieres cambiar de double a Double que es lo que creo que tratas de decir debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
//esto se llama Casting, sirve para cambiar de tipo de dato
//una variable
diurno_Double = (Double) diurno;
//con esto puedes verificar que la variable es de tipo Double
System.out.println(diurno_double.getClass());
```

Ahi ya transformaste tu variable double a Double
Aunque tambien nomas le cambias de double a Double, nomas con Double los valor que pongas detro deben tener decimales asi `diurno_Double = 10.00`
por ejemplo, si no, te marca error.